# Sending an email when a percentage of duration has passed

Tags: apex, formula, process-builder

I am trying to use Process Builder to workflow an Email...

Initially i used a formula to calculate the percentage complete from today:

```
IF(Course_Start_Date__c > TODAY(),0, 
IF(Course_End_Date__c < TODAY(),1,( 
TODAY() - Course_Start_Date__c) /(Course_End_Date__c - Course_Start_Date__c)))
```

I was reminded that formulas are calculated on the fly, it couldn't be used to trigger a Workflow, or Process Builder.

I have tried to enter the formula into the Process builder as well:

(whenever a record is created or edited)

Build Formula =

```
(TODAY() - [object__c].Course_Start_Date__c)/
([object__c].Course_End_Date__c - [object__c].Course_Start_Date__c) > 79
```

To update a checkbox to be true `Send_Email__c`, this isn't updating the field either.

Thanks

Comment: First of all make sure if your process is activated.

Comment: Process is active...and second of all?

Comment: Secondly I'd recommend to use workflow or trigger to update 'Send_email__c' and process builder afterwards for sending email based on the computed value result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to calculate the date in which the email should be sent, and then set the time-based delay to that value. First, create a formula field, type date or date/time, which calculates the date in which the email should be sent. Next, set the criteria to be active when that formula is in the future. Finally, set the time trigger equal to 0 days after the formula field's value. You can do this either in process builder or workflow rules. The trick is not to think of the date's calculation as a criteria, but as the offset when it should trigger.

This is what the workflow rule would look like:

[image]

This is what the process builder would look like:

[image: Process Builder]

Comment: Hey sfdcfox, I hear ya, I need a static date to work from. How are you with excel? Any ideas how to get a date from a range, when you have a percentage to work from (what date is 80% of 01/01/2000 - 11/01/2000)...

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh `StartDate + (EndDate - StartDate) * 0.80` would calculate 80% of the way through. EndDate - StartDate gives a number of days, multiply by 80%, then add the days back to the StartDate.

Comment: Hey sfdcfox, unfortunately the process isn't firing, nor being scheduled - I have the field formula, the steps through to schedule but it isnt being added to the "Paused and Waiting Interviews" list...

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh I'm investigating that, but the workflow rule should definitely work. I feel like there's still issues to track down with PB.

Comment: Hey sfdcfox, got it - The rule wasn't firing in PB because it has to be executed on specified changes to be time based. Cheers!